# How to prevent json_encode to encode existing json

Tags: php, php-7

I have an array like this:

```
    $json = '{ some already encoded json }';

    $data = [
        'success'       => $this->isSuccess(),
        'message'       => $this->getMessage(),
        'statusCode'    => (string)$this->getStatusCode(),
        'data'          => $json
    ];
```

in another function I call

```
json_encode ($data)
```

The problem is that the json_encode encodes also the already encoded json in the 'data' parameters and escapes it.
How can avoid this ? Is there a straightforward way to do this without changing my whole application ?

I would like to return a json like this:

```
{ 'success' : true, 'message': 'my message', 'statusCode': 200, 'data': { some already encoded json }}
```

Comment: Decode it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend decoding the json when appending it to data key in the array and later encode everything to json. Like this:

```
$json = '{ some already encoded json }';

$data = [
  'success'       => $this->isSuccess(),
  'message'       => $this->getMessage(),
  'statusCode'    => (string)$this->getStatusCode(),
  'data'          => json_decode($json)
];

json_encode($data);
```